# Swift/xcode set the size of ImageView

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2

I still have not code, but when I run the simulator the ImageView fills the view. How do I set the size of the fixed image or some percentage of the screen.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    red   = (0.0/255.0)
    green = (0.0/255.0)
    blue  = (0.0/255.0)
    lineWidth = 1.0
}
```

**In xcode**

[image]

**in the simulator**

[image]

Comment: Just simple click on add missing constraints. It will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints think you want the whole screen (that's why they are yellow). If you go to the icon with a triangle and two lines next to it in your storyboard at the bottom right, you can hit update frames and it will show you what it thinks you want. If you only want it to take up the middle of the screen but stretch to the left and right edges, you need to set the height. If you want dynamic height, you need to set the constraints to either pick a top or bottom constraint and set that. You can also just set it to be vertically centered in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Add constraint on imageview [left,right,fixed height ,HorzotalCenter in container & Vertical Center in container]

It will strech the image in width and always show in center, but if you don't want to strech image add[ [fixed width, fixed height ,HorzotalCenter in container & Vertical Center in container]] in width make it fixed as well.

If you want some percentage like you can use aspect ratio.

Hope you want like as per my understanding.